# Preloading the first image in a gallery using jacklmoore's colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, image, colorbox, bandwidth

Im planning to use the jacklmoore's colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) for a photo gallery and would like to preload the first image (or all images if possible) from the gallery so when a thumbnail is clicked there isn't along delay for users on slow internet or 3G connections.

The thumbnails are in a lower resolution with the main photos being 4x larger, so im trying to save bandwidth and improve speed where possible. Gallery sizes will vary between approximately 3 and 20 photos.

Colorbox does preload the 'next' and 'previous' photos, but doesn't appear to do the initial photo... does anyone have a solution or suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of preloading the first image.

```
var firstSrc = $('a.example').colorbox().first().attr('href');
var img = new Image;
img.src = firstSrc;
```